# (Kodular) The operation replace all cannot accept the arguments: , [*nothing*], [-], [*empty-string*]

Tags: android, codeblocks

I badly need help with the blocks. I'm using Dynamic Components on this one. So what I want is whenever I click the Vertical arrangement which is this
[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZR46.png) `application`
I want it to open a new screen Edit Screen and initialize the data from the vertical arrangement.

I tried the do it and the result is this...
[Do it Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrPvp.png)`do it`

Here are my blocks and let me know what will I add and remove.
Web Got Text(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPaJ.png)`your text`
For Each(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH9SI.jpg)`your text`
When Any Vertical Arrangement block(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XYSK.png)`your text`
It is not empty(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptj2s.png)